Joint Angles of PyBullet's Walker2D
I am using the Walker2D environment from pybullet_envs and I am trying to get the 6 joint angles in order to use them for an actual bipedal robot controlled by an Arduino.
I tried but didn't manage to find documentation such as the one of gym where the indices for the 6 joint angles are specified and their value are measured by rad. I found someone that indicated that inside the pybullet_envs GitHub documentation there is commented that the joint positions are the even elements of the observation space. I think that this true starting from the index 8 of the array for each column for the Walker2D env. My problem here is that I don't know the units of these values and I am not sure that they are correct. Is there an easier way to access the actual values (rad or deg) through the environment with the Physics Client Id and the Robot Id?

I believe that I found a solution.
The Walker2D object has an attribute called jdict which is a dictionary with Joint objects. Each Joint object has its own id as an attribute called jointIndex.
By having the ids of the joints the state of each joint can be gained by using the getJointState() from the pybullet package. The first element of the returned array is the angle of the joint (in radians?). The required inputs for the getJointState() function are the robot id and the joint id that its state is wanted.
Example
env = gym.make('Walker2BulletEnv-v0')
env.reset()

robot_id = env.env.robot.objects[0]
angle = pybullet.getJointState(robot_id, joint_id)[0]

Note: I think that if you are using more than one physics client the client id is also required and if there are more than one robots there should be some changes in order to get the correct robot id.
